# Django's YearArchiveView generic date view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

In Django there is a generic view called [`YearArchiveView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#yeararchiveview) that has an attribute called [`make_object_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#django.views.generic.dates.YearArchiveView.make_object_list).

Can somebody explain to me why this option actually exists at all?

Is it not logical that if I want a year based queryset, then it is obvious that I require a list of objects even if it only has one object.
Or I misunderstand something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TLDR;*** `make_object_list` returns all the objects for a given YearArchiveView in the view context under `object_list`. By default `make_object_list` is False which will result in the returned context `object_list` being empty.

So the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#django.views.generic.dates.YearArchiveView.make_object_list) is a little tricky to understand on this part. But hopefully this helps (tip: looking at the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/views/generic/dates/#YearArchiveView) really helps).

The `YearArchiveView` will by default return in the context the following:

- date_list: A date queryset returning all the months which have objects in them.
- year: a date object for the given year.
- next_year: a date object for first day of the next year.
- previous_year: a date object for the first day of the previous year.

You will notice in this list that the queryset objects for a given year whilst returned are empty.

**make_object_list**
So from above we know that the context by default will return a number of values relating to the dates of objects the, current year, previous and next but no actual queryset objects from the database.

Setting `make_object_list` to be true in the YearArchiveView, will result in all the queryset objects for a given year being passed back through the context so they can be used in the view.

Within the template the queryset objects will be available under the context `object_list`.

When in the template for a given YearArchiveView,you can then use:

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    <strong>item.title</strong> - {{ item.date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is much understandable for me now, but still have to work on it to understand it fully.
And one more question rises from this in me and that is, why then the other generic views like **MonthArchiveView** and **DayArchiveView** doesn't have this attribute too?

Comment: I believe there are two main reasons for this. Firstly, the amount of data returned. Secondly you are more likely to summarise items on a monthly or daily basis instead of a year.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @MattWritesCode reply I would say that there are use cases where you are only interested in building a navigation and not including much of the actual objects.

I imagine dealing with 1000s of articles, like big newspapers do. I would most likely want to display the actual contents in a separate view that supports paging (and maybe fine-grained permission-access, e.g. public posts and posts behind a paywall).

Good question though, I am just speculating about this. Since querysets are lazy I wouldn't expect it to be a big performance gain, but maybe in some way that is an aspect too. Would be interested in more opinions about it.